How to compare string variables containing spaces and special characters in a Bash script?
Below is a simple script where I compare two string variables $rev and $prev
#!/bin/sh

rev=`/usr/local/bin/svn info | grep "Revision"`

echo $rev

prev=`cat rev.txt`

if[ "$rev" = "$prev" ];
then
  echo "Are equal"
else
  echo "Differ => run"
fi

Both the rev and prev variable will contain strings of the form "Revision: nnn" where n's are digits. I was assuming that by encasing both $prev and $rev in quotes they would be interpreted as strings and compared however the output is:
./test.sh
Revision: 130
./test.sh: line 9: if\[ Revision: 130 = Revision: 130 \]: command not found
./test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `then' ./test.sh: line 10: `then'

I'm guessing that its the colon character in the strings that is causing the problem but I'm not sure. What syntax do I use to ensure that $prev and $rev are compared as raw strings ? Or is there something else that is causing the error ?
Thanks,
As above, no really, as above.

it's if [ not if[. Check your script with shellcheck.

BTW, echo $rev isn't reliable; don't use it. If you want to debug, xtrace (bash -x yourscript or set -x within the script to turn on tracing) is your friend.

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Also note that sh and bash are not the same thing, so the "bash" tag is not appropriate.  See Difference between sh and Bash.

(also, note that using backticks for command substitution is outdated even for sh -- the newer $( ) syntax nests better, generally behaves more intuitively, and has been standardized since the early 90s).

The error message just says that there is no command named if[. The syntax is if COMMAND and not ifCOMMAND. Aside from this, you didn't say how you executed your script. Unless you run it explicitly by bash SCRIPTNAME, it is not executed by bash, and your bash tag does not make sense.
